# stop animation after one repeat

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, uiimageview

i create an array of 2 images, animate then and everything work perfectly. but now i want the animation to stop after one repeat, i mean that the animation will start with the first image, move to second one and stop (and the second image will stay on my imageview). how can i do it?
here is my code:

```
    UIImage *mistakeOne = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Xmark.png"];
    UIImage *mistakeOneB = [UIImage imageNamed:@"XmarkWhite.png"];
    NSMutableArray *animation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:mistakeOne, mistakeOneB , nil];
    [mistakeNumberOne setAnimationImages:animation];
    mistakeNumberOne.animationDuration = 5.0;
    [mistakeNumberOne startAnimating]
```

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming mistakeNumberOne is a `UIImageView`

```
[mistakeNumberOne animationRepeatCount:1];
```

If you want to keep an image after the animation set the desired image in the UIImageview before the animation:

```
mistakeNumberOne.image = myDesiredImage;
```

After the animation it will show the image.

Putting it all together:

```
 UIImage *mistakeOne = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Xmark.png"];
 UIImage *mistakeOneB = [UIImage imageNamed:@"XmarkWhite.png"];
 NSMutableArray *animation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:mistakeOne, mistakeOneB , nil];
 [mistakeNumberOne setAnimationImages:animation];
 mistakeNumberOne.animationDuration = 5.0;
 [mistakeNumberOne animationRepeatCount:1];
 mistakeNumberOne.image = mistakeOneB;
 [mistakeNumberOne startAnimating];
```

Comment: the animation strat with the first image, then the second image is shown and after that my imageview(that contain my animation) is disappear(i don't see any image).

Answer (score 2):

Pfitz's answer is great for animating. However, for this is specific case where you have only two images and you only need to 'swap' between them its probably simpler to just change the image after a delay.

```
-(void)swapImage {

      [mistakeNumberOne setImage:mistakeOneB];
}
```

then delay swapImage:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(swapImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

hope this helps